# Awk Match String and Print ID String

Tags: awk

I am in the process of deleting old KMS keys on our system and learning bash. This forum has been super helpful with suggestions!

I am wanting to print key ID's of keys created in the year 2019. Here is my filter so far..

Input:

```
./ksctl keys list -l 100 | egrep -w 'id|name|createdAt' | awk '$2 ~ /"2019/ { print }' > keylist.txt
```

**Output:**

```
"createdAt": "2019-06-20T20:15:20Z",
"createdAt": "2019-06-20T20:15:20Z",
"createdAt": "2019-06-20T20:15:20Z",
"createdAt": "2019-06-20T20:15:20Z",
"createdAt": "2019-06-20T20:15:20Z",
etc..
```

This is wonderful, however I also need the KeyID printed with this match.

Desired Output:

```
"createdAt": "2019-06-20T20:15:20Z",
"id": "asdf1234",
```

Comment: Please show the result of `./ksctl keys list -l 100`. Wouldn't a JSON parser be a more solid solution?

Comment: I cannot show the output as it is confidential information. All this does is talk to our KMS and returns key information, with -l 100 being passed as a limiter of 100 keys to print.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the `id` line is always after the `createdAt` line, use `getline;` to read it.

```
./ksctl keys list -l 100 | 
    egrep -w 'id|name|createdAt' | 
    awk '$2 ~ /"2019/ { print; getline; print }' > keylist.txt
```

Comment: The "id" is actually before "createdAt", my mistake on that one.

Comment: If I run the below:

`./ksctl keys list -l 100 | egrep -w 'id|name|createdAt' | awk '$2 ~ /"2019/ { getline; print; getline; print }' > keylist.txt`

I get the output below:

`"name": "key 1",
"id": "asdf1234",
"name": "key 2",
"id": "zxcv5678",`

This is very close to where I want the output. I just need the "id" only.

Comment: You might be better off using the `-B` option to `grep`.

Comment: `| grep -B 1 '"2019'`

Comment: I got it!  

I actually found out I needed the key name, not the ID.  

Using this input:  

`./ksctl keys list -l 100 | egrep -w 'id|name|createdAt' | awk '$2 ~ /"2019/ { getline; print }' > keylist.txt`  

I got my desired output of names. 

`"name": "key1",
"name": "key2",`  

Thank you @Barmar!